# Where does UIElement.add_MouseDown come from in f#?

Tags: wpf, f#

I'm trying to understand why the following code works (taken from http://jyliao.blogspot.com/2007/10/learning-wpf.html):

```
open System
open System.Windows
open System.Windows.Input

(* From Chap 1 - HandleAnEvent.cs *)
let WindowOnMouseDown sender (args:MouseButtonEventArgs) =
   let win = unbox<Window> sender
   let str = sprintf "Window clicked with %A button at point (%A)" args.ChangedButton (args.GetPosition win)
   MessageBox.Show(str)|>ignore

let win = new Window()
win.Title <- "Handle an Event"
win.add_MouseDown(new MouseButtonEventHandler(WindowOnMouseDown))

#if COMPILED
[<STAThread()>]
do 
    let app =  new Application() in
    app.Run(win) |> ignore
#endif
```

The part that I don't understand is the call to `add_MouseDown`. When i hover my mouse over the call in VS, it tells me that the method comes from the UIElement class, but I can't find any reference to this method in the .NET class library.

In F# I would have expected the call to be:

```
win.MouseDown.AddHandler (new MouseButtonEventHandler(WindowOnMouseDown))
```

When I make this change the message box that pops up no longer shows the coordinates within the window at which you click. Instead it shows coordinates that are independent of the position of the mouse click within the window, but change as you move the window around on your screen. So it seems like the `sender` parameter is referring to some UI element other than the window.

Does anyone understand why using add_MouseDown works (and where the existence of this method is documented), and why using AddHandler doesn't work?

I'm using VS2010, F# 2.0, .NET 3.0 libraries.

**Update:**

Ah, I just realized that I was *wrong* that using AddHandler works differently than using add_MouseDown. What I had actually been doing was adding two event handlers one after the other using the two different approaches:

```
win.add_MouseDown(new MouseButtonEventHandler(WindowOnMouseDown))
win.MouseDown.AddHandler (new MouseButtonEventHandler(WindowOnMouseDown))
```

This pops up two message windows, the first shows the correct position within the window, the second shows this other goofy position. But if I truly replace the add_MouseDown call with the addHandler call, then I do get the same results.

So for this part of it, I think my real question is why does the second event handler report a different position. But perhaps that's best handled as a separate question.

Comment: Does it work if you add a type annotation: (`sender: obj`)? As it is, the function is generic, which doesn't match the type of `MouseButtonEventHandler`.

Comment: Your code has a few issues: (1) `string.Format` doesn't compile in F# (2) you're not using `sender` anyway (other than to store it in `win`).

Comment: @Daniel (1) whoops, I had changed this in my code but copied directly from the website when creating the question, just changed it above (2) that's incorrect, win is passed to GetPosition

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why it's not working, but you can accomplish the same thing by passing a closure to `Add`:

```ml
let win = Window()
win.MouseDown.Add(fun args ->
  let str = sprintf "Window clicked with %O button at point (%O)" args.ChangedButton (args.GetPosition(win))
  MessageBox.Show(str) |> ignore)
```

Now it's clear what `win` refers to (and no need for unboxing). This is better than the type-less `sender` param anyway. Maybe it will work as expected?

Comment: Yes, that works great (as long as it's the only event handler - see my update above).

Answer (score 0):

`add_MouseDown` is the name of the *add* accessor of the `MouseDown` event.
In C#, this method is called by writing `win.MouseDown += ...`.
In VB.Net, it's called by writing `AddHandler(win, AddressOf ...)`.

F# doesn't have a special syntax for adding event handlers, so you need to call it explicitly.

Comment: "*F# doesn't have a special syntax for adding event handlers*" It kind of does -- [`Event.add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340422.aspx).

Comment: Do you know where I can find documentation about this? i.e., where is it documented that the add accessor of an event corresponds to an add_event method in f#? Note that intellisense in VS doesn't display this method, which seems strange because it certainly seems to exist. And Do you understand why using AddHandler leads to different behavior?

Comment: More importantly F# does not _need_ special syntax for adding event handlers, because events are _just objects_ with methods like `AddHandler`. This is pretty cool, because you can use them as arguments to functions and so things lik .NET Rx becomes a lot nicer!